# How can I get around using xclip in the Linux subsystem on Win 10?

Tags: clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On a Linux subsytem on Windows 10 you get an error when using xclip, ex:

```
cat some/file.txt | xclip
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

There is no Desktop (UI), so of course there isn't a clipboard to be used. Could there be a workaround to make it work with the Windows clipboard?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [WSL issue #1069](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1069) for two workarounds:

> Just to clarify for anyone who stumbles upon this thread, to use type
>   `cat filePath | clip.exe` into the command prompt.
>   - [JetStarBlues commented on Feb 8](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1069#issuecomment-363990534)

Or:

> I can confirm that having Xming running and configuring the `DISPLAY`
>   env var is enough to make something go to the windows clipboard:
>
> ```
> $ export DISPLAY=:0
> $ echo 'some text' | xclip -selection clipboard
> ```
>
> This works just fine. Apparently using the primary clipboard also
>   works fine, so I'm guessing Xming will redirect both to the windows
>   clipboard.
>   - [mateusmedeiros commented on Sep 9, 2016](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1069#issuecomment-245793843)

Comment: For WSL, I find X410 equality good at solving the "Can't open display" error.

Comment: I am having `Error: Can't open display: :0` error

Comment: This worked for me on Linux Virtualbox VMs and Windows Hosts.

Comment: clip.exe works perfect! for more information on the usage type `clip.exe /?`

Comment: And to *get* the clipboard content inside WSL: `powershell.exe Get-Clipboard`

Answer (score 15):

`clip.exe  < ~/.ssh/id_rsa` worked for me to copy my ssh keys to github on WSL2.

Comment: I am not sure clip.exe will work on Ubuntu (unless you using wine first no?)

Comment: @BookOfZeus The system described in the question is Ubuntu in WSL on Windows 10. In such an environment, it is possible to run Windows programs (like `clip.exe`) from within the WSL system.

Comment: Good to know! I never used windows nor never used WSL. You got my vote!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using temux all the time,
adding this to my .tmux.conf enables me to copy and past without installing an X server :)

```
#to be able to use mouse buttons and scroll:
set -g mouse on

#to copy to Windows clipboard by marking text
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel clip.exe

#to be able to paste by right clicking (like in default Windows Terminal)
unbind-key MouseDown3Pane
bind-key -n MouseDown3Pane run "tmux set-buffer \"$(powershell.exe -command Get-Clipboard | tr -s '\r\n' ' ')\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Comment: now even better, with
 | tr -s '\r\n' ' '
instead of sed it wont execute commands if you accidentally copy a "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file named, say "pbcopy" and fill it with

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FILE=$(pwd)/$1
cat "${FILE}" | clip.exe
```

Then move the file to your bin directory.

```
mv pbcopy ~/bin
```

Now you can use pbcopy on your wsl to copy file contents to clipboard.

```
pbcopy my/file/path
```